# Iterating and printing a list in the wrong way

Tags: python, python-2.7

Having the following two list:

```
sist = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
numbers = [2,1,4]
```

I want to print the elements of `sist` the number of times of the same index of `numbers`.

This means that in the example posted my desired output is:

```
item1
item1
item2
item3
item3
item3
item3
```

This is what I've tried with no success:

```
for idx in xrange(len(sist)):
    for num in numbers:
        i = 0
        print num
        while i < num:
            print sist[idx]
            i = i + 1
```

I think I'm iterating in the wrong way as I'm getting this output:

```
2
item1
item1
1
item1
4
item1
item1
item1
item1
2
item2
item2
1
item2
4
item2
item2
item2
item2
2
item3
item3
1
item3
4
item3
item3
item3
item3
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sist = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
numbers = [2,1,4]

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    for j in numbers[i]:
        print(sist[i])
    print('')
```

I think this is the desired output you are looking for. It iterates over the numbers array and uses each element as the range for the second for loop. since numbers and sist are the same length you can just use `i` as the index for `sist`

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to use nested `for` loops like this, you could do

```
for item, rep in zip(sist, numbers):
    for _ in range(rep):
        print(item)
```

Output

```
item1
item1
item2
item3
item3
item3
item3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use zip function to join the two lists at their corresponding indexes, and then print the first element (from sist) the number of times as the second element (from numbers)

```
sist = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
numbers = [2,1,4]
for x, y in zip(sist, numbers):
    for _ in range(y):
        print(x)
```

The output is -

```
item1
item1
item2
item3
item3
item3
item3
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement other answers, you can avoid nested loops like so:

```
from __future__ import print_function # This isn't needed in Python 3.

for n, item in zip(numbers, sist):
    print([item] * n, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

This calls for a nested for loop, like the following:

```
>>> sist = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
>>> numbers = [2,1,4]
>>> for i in xrange(len(numbers)):
    for j in xrange(numbers[i]):
        print sist[i]


item1
item1
item2
item3
item3
item3
item3
```